# Unable to upload image in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am trying to upload image using php. But it is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    ?>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" >
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? An errors? Have you checked the log files?

Comment: you can easily upload an image by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form you are missing enctype

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your permissions are set correctly on the server. The folder you are uploading to should have writable permissions and the server must allow uploads.

The file could also be too large if there is a file size limit.

You must use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as a form attribute for file uploads. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 1):

First change your form to

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second check your folder permissions  if you are uploading to server
the folder permission should be 0775 or 0777
If not you can change it before uploading.

```
chmod(0777,true);
```

Third Check your php.ini file for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

you can check it by printing `phpinfo();` or in command window `php --ini`

Comment: Great answer man.  Thnx

Answer (score 0):

**Errors**

1. If you use same file to upload image then this part should be remove `action="upload.php"` and add  as `action="#"`
2. Missing `enctype` (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`)
3. File move directory is not set (`$target_file`)

**Tip**

1. Follow this Link [PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). This Contain all the methods